# covariance of each key in a dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, covariance

I have a list, which is a set of tickers. For each ticker, I get the the daily return going back six months. I then want to compute the covariance between each ticker. I am having trouble with `np.cov`, here is my code to test COV:

```
newStockDict = {}
for i in newList_of_index:
    a = Share(i)
    dataB = a.get_historical(look_back_date, end_date)
    stockData = pd.DataFrame(dataB)
    stockData['Daily Return'] = ""
    yList = []
    for y in range(0,len(stockData)-1):
        stockData['Daily Return'][y] = np.log(float(stockData['Adj_Close'][y])/float(stockData['Adj_Close'][y+1]))

    yList = stockData['Daily Return'].values.tolist()
    newStockDict[stockData['Symbol'][0]] = yList

g = (np.cov(pd.Series((newStockDict[newList_of_index[0]]))), pd.Series(((newStockDict[newList_of_index[1]]))))
return g
```

My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Udaya\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Udaya/Documents/Python Scripts/SR_YahooFinanceRead.py", line 150, in <module>
    print CumReturnStdDev(stock_list)
  File "C:/Users/Udaya/Documents/Python Scripts/SR_YahooFinanceRead.py", line 132, in CumReturnStdDev
    g = (np.cov(pd.Series((newStockDict[newList_of_index[0]]))), pd.Series(((newStockDict[newList_of_index[1]]))))
  File "C:\Users\Udaya\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 1885, in cov
    X -= X.mean(axis=1-axis, keepdims=True)
  File "C:\Users\Udaya\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 66, in _mean
    ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.float64' and 'str'
>>> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.float64' and 'str'
```

I've tried using `pd.cov` on a dataframe, then `np.cov`. Nothing works. Here I am actually appending the daily returns to a list, then to a dictionary, before I manually calculate an `n` by `n` covariance matrix. But I am unable to get `np.cov` to work.

Please help. The idea is I can easily construct a dataframe of N tickers, with each row being a daily return. but am unable to compute cov with said dataframe, thus this df-->list-->dict process.

Comment: Not answering the question, but your for loop is better spelt without an iteration variable:

`stockData['Daily Return'] = [np.log(float(a) / float(b)) for a, b in zip(stockData['Adj_Close'], stockData['Adj_Close'][1:])]`

Comment: What is `stockData['Daily Return'] = ""` doing? And what is the value of `ylist` if you print it out?

Comment: @Eric--value of yList is a list of daily returns. stockData['Daily Return'] is adding a column daily return to the dataframe "stockData".

Comment: @Eric -- will " stockData['Daily Return'] = [np.log(float(a) / float(b)) for a, b in zip(stockData['Adj_Close'], stockData['Adj_Close'][1:])] "  essentially do the same thing without looping? I was reading about this but I didn't understand it completely

Comment: I want to see the actual value of `ylist` (or at least `ylist[:5], ylist[-5:]`), not just your summary of what you think it contains

Comment: [-0.0036892847747957325, -0.0024519832472866452, 0.0, 0.0049099934975557853, -0.0024580102502692264, 0.0073922307874905169, -0.0041135393257921418,..., -0.0072229224102841371, 0.0083387863906776664, -0.0016733293855206528, 0.0059623802496525987, ''] for each stock

Comment: I've figured it out thanks, had to drop the "" at the end